# Read data from Cassandra in spark-shell

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I want to read data from cassandra node in my client node on :

This is what i tried :

```sh
spark-shell --jars /my-dir/spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.3.2.jar.
```

```scala
val df = spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")\
  .option("keyspace","my_keyspace")\
  .option("table","my_table")\
  .option("spark.cassandra.connection.host","Hostname of my Cassandra node")\
  .option("spark.cassandra.connection.port","9042")\
  .option("spark.cassandra.auth.password","mypassword)\
  .option("spark.cassandra.auth.username","myusername")\
  .load
```

I'm getting this error: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.DefaultSource$`

and

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/configuration/ConfigurationException.
```

Am I missing any properties? What this error is for ? How would I resolve this ?

Spark-version:2.3.2, DSE version 6.7.8

Comment: are you running this on the DSE node itself?

Comment: I'm not aware, since I'm new to this, But I can tell you one thing that on checking "show version" , I'm getting this result:
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | DSE 6.7.8 | CQL spec 3.4.5 | DSE protocol v2]

Comment: @Alex No , Spark command is running on different node(edge node basically)

Comment: ok, my answer covers all options :-)

Answer (score 3):

The Spark Cassandra Connector itself depends on the number of other dependencies, that could be missing here - this happens because you're providing only one jar, and not all required dependencies.

Basically, in your case you need to have following choice:

- If you're running this on the DSE node, then you can use built-in Spark, if the cluster has Analytics enabled - in this case, all jars and properties are already provided, and you only need to provide username and password when starting spark shell via `dse -u user -p password spark`
- if you're using external Spark, then it's better to use so-called [BYOS (bring your own spark)](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.7/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/spark/byosOverview.html) - special version of the Spark Cassandra Connector with all dependencies bundled inside, and you can download jar from [DataStax's Maven repo](https://repo.datastax.com/public-repos/com/datastax/dse/dse-byos_2.11/6.7.8/), and use with `--jars`
- you can still use open source Spark Cassandra Connector, but in this case, it's better to use `--packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.3.2` so Spark will able to fetch all dependencies automatically.

P.S. In case of open source Spark Cassandra Connector I would recommend to use version 2.5.1 or higher, although it requires Spark 2.4.x (although 2.3.x may work) - [this version has improved support for DSE, plus a lot of the new functionality not available in the earlier versions](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2020/05/advanced-apache-cassandra-analytics-now-open-all).  Plus for that version there is a [version that includes all required dependencies (so-called assembly)](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly_2.11/2.5.1) that you can use with `--jars` if your machine doesn't have access to the internet.

Comment: Tried using BYOS , Downloaded jar from->  https://repo.datastax.com/public-repos/com/datastax/dse/dse-byos_2.11/6.7.8/ , and ran as "spark-shell --jars /my-dir/spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.3.2.jar . " , I'm getting error as "java.io.IOException: Failed to open native connection to Cassandra at {hostname}:porntnumber" on running command  mentioned above in the question , val df = .......

Comment: use something like `nc -vz host 9042` to check that all nodes of the cluster are reachable from the Spark node